# React-native sms retriever not working as expected

Tags: react-native, sms-retriever-api

I am working on a React Native app - sms-retriever API to read SMS automatically to retrieve OTP from message Following this article: https://github.com/Bruno-Furtado/react-native-sms-retriever

```
_onSmsListenerPressed = async () => {
  alert('waiting for SMS')
  try {
    const registered = await SmsRetriever.startSmsRetriever();
    if (registered) {
      SmsRetriever.addSmsListener(event => {
        console.log(event.message);
        alert(event.message);
        this.setState({message:event.message});
        SmsRetriever.removeSmsListener();
      }); 
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
};
```

I'm running on an Android device
When I press the button which calls the above message, it should start listening
But when an SMS is received, it doesn't alert with SMS message
What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Is it because SmsRetriever.addSmsListener returns a Promise? Have you tried adding await in front of it?

Comment: Have you configured hash code and proper sms format?